# iOS/Phonegap: jQuery Mobile Error loading page

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I have been using jQuery Mobile for a few years now for building apps based on Phonegap Build. Since iOS 10 it seems regular linking to sub pages results in "error loading page". What I do is very simpel:

index.html => a jQuery call loads the jQuery Mobile listview with:

```
<a href="item.html?id=1">
```

Next I have that file (item.html) which is linked to in the same directory, so the file does exist.

What could this be and why did it stop working? On Android is works fine btw. I have "cordova-plugin-whitelist" included in my project with the following option:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Anyone that has had this problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: add this meta tag in index.html and try **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:" />**

Comment: Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should be just fine to pass variables to external pages. Just know that URL variables will only be passed to external pages. Meaning that if you already have an external page in the DOM, you will have to re-load the page to pass it variables again.

I believe that older versions of jQuery Mobile hamper this behavior but you should be good to go with anything 1.0 or later.

Also read the bottom of this page, "Known Limitations": http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html (specifically the second from the bottom bullet)

To reload a page with jQuery Mobile you can use the $.mobile.changePage() function and set the reloadPage option to true:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-link-id', 'click', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage({ reloadPage : true });
    return false;
});
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: It used to work fine, so I guess it might be Cordova related. Also it's not the variables, it also doesn't work when using item.html (so without variables).